# how to Giphy video get Thumbnail image and Api integrate in android studio?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, giphy

I have display search Giphy video thumbnail image in gridview and after this image click play.how to do get thumbnail image? how to Giphy API integration in Android Studio.

How to search video play in player?

Comment: To integrate Giphy API in Android you need an API key, read everything about it here
https://developers.giphy.com/docs/

Comment: I know but how using api key video display in gridview.